# split string into multi arrays?

Tags: php

i have a string like this one

```
$sitesinfo = 'site 1 titles-example1.com/
site 2 titles-example2.com/
site 3 titles-example3.com/
site 4 titles-example4.com/
site 5 titles-example5.com/';
```

i used to split lines into 1 array like this

```
$lines = explode("/",$sitesinfo);
```

then while i loop i got each line into an array object without problems
what i need to do to split each line into 2 pieces and add each piece into an array so the result be like this

```
$titles = array("site 1 titles","site 2 titles","site 3 titles","site 4 titles","site 5 titles");
$domains = array("example1.com","example2.com","example3.com","example4.com","example5.com");
```

so i can use them in script

i did a lot of tries but fail :(

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
  $t = explode('-', trim($line), 2);
  if (count($t) < 2) {
    echo "Failed to parse the line $line";
    continue;
  }
  $titles[] = $t[0];
  $domains[] = $t[1];
}
```

Explanation: each line split by '-' symbol into exactly 2 parts (if there's less, that's an error - the line doesn't contain '-', and thus shouldn't be processed at all). The first part is pushed into `$titles` array, the second - into `$domains`.

Comment: sorry for the downvote, but I don't like this solution because it assumes exploding at "/" like what OP had, and goes from there.  What happens when a URL doesn't end in "/"?  It would fail if the URL doesn't end in that, and even if it does, it doesn't put it back on, since it *is* part of the URL.  At a minimum, should be exploded at the line break (if you add this to your post then i'll give you vote back :) )

Comment: well you didn't show where `$lines` is coming from, so it is assumed you started your code where the OP left off. If that is not what `$lines` represents in your code, then show what `$lines` is coming from.

Comment: And, by the way, the domains the OP wished to see (in his example) are without the ending '/' symbol... Well, whatever.

Comment: excuse me, but you did not offer a complete solution.  Your code starts with the assumption that `$lines` is an array of rows from the OP's `$sitesinfo`. Since part of the problem involves a single string, your code either a) skips a step, or b) starts where OP left off with that explode. Instead of getting your panties in a wad over this fact, fix your code and get your vote back. It's that simple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12955/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-crayon-violent)

Answer (score 1):

First of all split the string into each line (by the line ending character).

Then split each line into two parts at the first `-` and add those parts to the result. You can later on give each part a name on it's own:

Example/[Demo](http://codepad.org/bTvUGYJ3):

```
$lines = explode("\r\n", $sitesinfo);
$r = array(null, null);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    list($r[0][], $r[1][]) = explode("-", $line, 2) + array(1 => NULL);
}
list($titles, $domains) = $r;
unset($r);
```

Or the regex variant ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jMsuuP)):

```
preg_match_all('~([^-]+)-(.*)~', $sitesinfo, $matches);
list(, $titles, $domains) = $matches;
unset($matches);
```

Result:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "site 1 titles"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "site 2 titles"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "site 3 titles"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "site 4 titles"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "site 5 titles"
}
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "example1.com/"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "example2.com/"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "example3.com/"
  [3]=>
  string(13) "example4.com/"
  [4]=>
  string(13) "example5.com/"
}
```

Comment: +1. ) I rarely use `list` operator (may be because it's too similar, but not quite to `($foo, @bar...) = ` Perl construct, and I'm real afraid of bugs that might be introduced by that not-quite-similarity), but I enjoy seeing others using it. )

Comment: @raina77ow: Yeah, can be useful, added another example.

Answer (score 1):

regex alternative:

```
$sitesinfo = 'site 1 titles-example1.com/
site 2 titles-example2.com/
site 3 titles-example3.com/
site 4 titles-example4.com/
site 5 titles-example5.com/';

preg_match_all('~([^-]+)-(.*)~',$sitesinfo,$matches);
$titles = array_map('trim',$matches[1]);
$domains = array_map('trim',$matches[2]);
```